# How do I strongly type a function returning a property of an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function named `getPropertyReference` that returns a reference of a property in an object. It's mostly for my sanity to prevent typing `this.object.myNestedObject.property = ...` over and over.

Here's the complete function:

```
export function getPropertyReference(object: {[key: PropertyKey]: any}, prop: PropertyKey): any {
    return {
        get value(): any {
            return object[prop];
        },

        set value(to: any) {
            object[prop] = to;
        }
    }.value; // return the getters and setters without having to access ref.value
}
```

Usage goes something along the lines of

```
const ref = getPropertyReference(this.object.myNestedObject, "foo");

ref = 4;

console.log(ref); // 4
console.log(this.object.myNestedObject.foo); // 4

// etc
```

That code works fine. However, it has a return type of `any`, and it would be much nicer to get a return type of `object[prop]`. My code looks like this:

```
export function getPropertyReference<O = {[key: PropertyKey]: any}, K = keyof O>(object: O, prop: K): O[K] {
    // same code here
}
```

Typescript complains about this here. "Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'O'." How can I fix this?

Comment: The function code you provided [results in a TypeError at runtime](https://tsplay.dev/mx66bw) ("Assignment to constant variable".) when I try to execute it with example data. Can you provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (no TypeScript necessary) by editing your question to include a [runnable JS snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: @jsejcksn this sounds like pointer in C. JS/TS does not have anything similar. The best you can do is the version with `ref.value`. But then, why bother with this construct, create a reference to the object. `const obj = this.object.myNestedObject;` and use it like `obj.foo = 4;`

Comment: @Thomas That's exactly how I interpreted it as well. A higher order function which creates and returns a closure — functional get (0 args) and set (1 arg) — would work, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close with the last type you tried. Problem is just that you did `=` in the generic definition, when you should have used `extends`. For example, `K = keyof O` means `K` can be absolutely any type, but will default to `keyof O` if no type is supplied. Instead, it needs to be `K extends keyof O`, which will restrict `K` to the keys of the object.

```
export function getPropertyReference<
  O extends { [key: string]: any },
  K extends keyof O
>(object: O, prop: K): O[K] {
  return {
    get value(): O[K] {
      return object[prop];
    },

    set value(to: O[K]) {
      object[prop] = to;
    },
  }.value;
}

const example = { name: "bob", age: 12 };

let age = getPropertyReference(example, "age"); // number
let error = getPropertyReference(example, "doesNotExist"); // compile time error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwObAwAKUEYwsAngErAIXDrAA8AUHHACpygyMAmAZzgBvOAG0A1sEoAuOIJhRMKPAF15AQxSU4AXwA07OAGkeIPiiFxplCAi6sAfAAoIAIwBWwDPM4G4MFIweRMASj9xEzVRYyhCJChcEWMOAngAN00AGyRgFwiuKJiUjjK4eJhE3A9vDHEgsjUAblT9IzbBQjgs3PyYCEjosNjyjlqfGAbgmIBeOAHW8sNjPQA6XrzWvVZWNBxFc00AWzBs4Dh5sRQT4HkAIncPe4DNAnkARgAmfVbWc-gbwu83SJDIFBgNDoDCYLlAJzOwAC9yB9zCzTgAHpMXAUEhju4KP9uhRSFBLvhCGDyFRaPR4rD4adzsj+BBgIIAHIQGAAURAmEUaIx2Lg+1OmHOC0wxwupOgQA)

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired outcome described in the question. I added a couple of `console.log` lines to demonstrate: [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQeevw)

Comment: Since you said the code was working, i didn't check the logic, just the types. Looking at the logic in more detail, what you're trying to do isn't going to work. The getter is evaluated just once, as part of the return statement. You now have a plain primitive number, and you assign that to the local variable `age`. Assigning something new to `age` will have no effect on the object.

Answer (score 1):

> @Thomas That's exactly how I interpreted it as well. A higher order function which creates and returns a closure — functional get (0 args) and set (1 arg) — would work, too

OK, this is possible:

```
function getPropertyReference<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(object: T, prop: K) {
  function ref(): T[K];
  function ref(value: T[K]): void;
  function ref() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return object[prop];
    }

    object[prop] = arguments[0];
    return; //Not all code paths return a value.(7030)
  }

  return ref;
}


const example = { name: "bob", age: 12 };

let age = getPropertyReference(example, "age"); // number

console.log(age());

age(18);

console.log(age());
```